# How to Change Default Printer on Windows 7 / VDI Environment?

Tags: printing, window

We currently have an issue with our VDI (virtual environment users) on Windows 7 setting their default printer.

Everytime the user logs in the default printer is set to the local USB one (not the network printer we want it to be set to).

Is there anyway around this?  i have tried setting the default in printer settings.
Im guessing this is a group policy issue?